# Get sum of array columns in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

We have arrays:

```
[1, 2, 3, 0]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2]
```

Need to get a one array, indexes which is will be like a sum of columns. Expected result:

```
[3, 6, 6, 0]
```

Comment: Sometimes you get lucky and people don't even question the fact that you showed no efforts whatsoever. You got lucky ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) in combination with [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
var array = [
        [1, 2, 3, 0],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2]
    ],
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        a.forEach(function (b, i) {
            r[i] = (r[i] || 0) + b;
        });
        return r;
    }, []);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: How does it happen ?

Comment: it iterates over the outer array and then adds each value of the inner array to the same position in the result array.

Comment: @NinaScholz reduce, my favorite!

Comment: I don't figure out what should I change to make this for rows instead of columns. Probably `table.reduce(function (r, a) {
   r.forEach(function(b, i) {
    a[i] = (a[i] || 0) + b;
   });
   return a;
  }, []);` is not the right way.

Comment: @user3654571 it's not the right place to ask in comments another problem, but you could map the sums with `result = array.map(function (aa) { return aa.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }); });`

Comment: I know but probably if I would ask it separately it will be closed for duplicate or something. Anyway, your solution still computes the sum on the columns :D

Comment: @user3654571, i don't get you. it returns `[6, 6, 3]`, as expected, with the above data.

Comment: Totally forgot the `reduce` support the second argu, nice and clear solution for the matrix calc.

Answer (score 10):

Basic for loop,

```
var arr = [[1, 2, 3, 0],[1, 2, 3],[1, 2]];
var res = [];

for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
 for(var j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++){
  res[j] = (res[j] || 0) + arr[i][j];
 }
}

console.log(res); //[3, 6, 6, 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function arrayColumnsSum(array) {
  return array.reduce((a, b)=> // replaces two elements in array by sum of them
    a.map((x, i)=>             // for every `a` element returns...
      x +                      // its value and...
      (b[i] || 0)              // corresponding element of `b`,
                               // if exists; otherwise 0
    )
  )
}

console.log(arrayColumnsSum([
  [1, 2, 3, 0]
 ,[1, 2, 3]
 ,[1, 2]
]))
```

Comment: awsome, Thnks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this using **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** and **[`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)**

```js
// function to get sum of two array where array length of a is greater than b
function sum(a, b) {
  return a.map((v, i) => v + (b[i] || 0))
}

var res = [
  [1, 2, 3, 0],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2]
  // iterate over array to reduce summed array
].reduce((a, b) => a.length > b.length ? sum(a, b) : sum(b, a))


document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```